DataReader KeyError: 'structure' for Oecd data
I'm running the following code to retrive data from OECD:
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web 

start_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 31)

#SPECIFIC DATABASE WITHIN OECD API
database = 'MEI_FIN'

df1 = web.DataReader(database, 'oecd', start_date, end_date)
df1

I'm reciving the following error:
File D:\conda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\io\jsdmx.py:44, in read_jsdmx(path_or_buf)
     41 else:
     42     data = json.loads(jdata, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
---> 44 structure = data["structure"]
     45 index = _parse_dimensions(structure["dimensions"]["observation"])
     46 columns = _parse_dimensions(structure["dimensions"]["series"])

KeyError: 'structure'

In general, I'm having huge troubles trying to retrieve data from the OECD via Python; almost everything that I tried is not working. I would gladly receive some tips on how to approach this issue.

Always include the full complete stack trace, not just a part of it.

I have the same issue.
I think pandas_datareader is no longer maintained.
These are the evidences.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pulse/monthly
https://app.codecov.io/gh/pydata/pandas-datareader

If you want to get OECD data, you should use the API(https://data.oecd.org/api/) that OECD provides.
I guess the main reason of this issue coming from the updates of the API.
Please refer to the following documents to update your queries by the end of 2023:
